# Download Azure blobs to browser using BlobDownloadToOptions

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am able to download blobs from Azure but when I get to download larger file but I am unable to download larger files of 2 Gig. I found a solution that I can use BlobDownloadToOptions.  The code is shown below, it shows the code is required a path to download,  whereas I want to download to browser. How can I modify the code to download to browser?   I am using ASP.Net webform

```
public static async Task DownloadBlobWithTransferOptionsAsync(
BlobClient blobClient,
string localFilePath)
  {
    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

var transferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
{
    // Set the maximum number of parallel transfer workers
    MaximumConcurrency = 2,

    // Set the initial transfer length to 8 MiB
    InitialTransferSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024,

    // Set the maximum length of a transfer to 4 MiB
    MaximumTransferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024
};

BlobDownloadToOptions downloadOptions = new BlobDownloadToOptions()
{
    TransferOptions = transferOptions
};

await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(fileStream, downloadOptions);

fileStream.Close();
```

}

I took the code from the below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download

Answer (score 1):

***I have uploaded larger files >1gb to my container in Azure blob storage manually:***

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

I could download the larger files(>1gb) from Azure blob storage to browser using below code:

```cs
 public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadBlob(string blobName)
        {
            var _connectionString = "your_storage_connection_string";
            var _containerName = "your_container_name";
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString);
            var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(_containerName);
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

            var transferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
            {
                MaximumConcurrency = 2,
                InitialTransferSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024,
                MaximumTransferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024
            };

            BlobDownloadToOptions downloadOptions = new BlobDownloadToOptions()
            {
                TransferOptions = transferOptions
            };

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(memoryStream, downloadOptions);


            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + blobName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
            Response.End();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**View for downloading blob:**

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("DownloadBlob", "Blob", new { blobName = "your_blob_name_to_download" })">Download Blob</a>
```

***Downloading the larger files(>1gb) from Azure blob storage to browser:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes it helped me thanks.  Beside your solution I also tested out   blobClient.OpenRead(); it worked out fine but I am not sure what is the difference between   DownLoadAsync() vs OpenRead() and when to use which one.

Comment: @Jashvita, Glad that it could help you resolve the issue. I have no idea how [OpenRead()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.openread?view=azure-dotnet) works. Regarding [DownloadToAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadtoasync?view=azure-dotnet) which I used in my code, it downloads a file from the Blob Storage to a memory stream (where the file gets downloaded) asynchronously.